# How to set authToken to localStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, local-storage

There is a misunderstanding with login in React.

I make request with `login, password` then get response with **hash**.

The **hash** I have to save in localStorage or sessionStorage, it depends of (remember or not) checkbox option in Login form.

I subscribe to store, and there save my hash to localStore(or sessionStore)

```js
store.subscribe(() => saveStorage(store.getState()));

function saveStorage({ logInfo }) {
    const state = {
        logInfo
    };

    try {
        const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);

        if (sessionStorage.getItem('session')) {
            return sessionStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
        }

        localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

In logInfo - I have hash, username etc..

It all works, but I'm sure it's not right way to save it like that, because every time when route link changes  `store.subscribe` executes again and again

Please explain to me how to make it in right way..

Comment: Maybe you can check if the token exists before running the function

Comment: "every time when route link changes store.subscribe executes again and again" The code does not show this part. When do you run the code?

Comment: @dev_junwen I thought about it, but is it good place to save it there?